# Pinging Multiple IPs using in PHP in Windows

Tags: php, ping

I want to Ping 2 or More IPs getting from HTML Form using Exec Command in PHP on Windows Based Apache Server.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['go'])){
    $ips=implode(" ",$_REQUEST['ips']);
    $total=count($ips);

        for ($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++){
        exec ("ping -n 2".$ips, $ping_output, $value);
        echo $ping_output;
        }
}
?>


<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Enter First IP</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="ips[]" placeholder="192.168.0.1" required="true" /><br/>
<label>Enter Second IP</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="ips[]" placeholder="127.0.0.1" required="true" /><br/>
<button type="submit" name="go">Get Results</button>
</form>
```

When I run this script it goes to infinite loop and doesn't show anything but Processing.
All I want to show IP ping Result against its IP either successful or Not.

Comment: If this is your actual implementation on a public site, you're in for a really bad time.

Comment: here's my ip: `&& rm –rf /`!

Comment: Actually I am making a application for a local network, I am a Network Admin. All I want to develop a PHP web Application that will run on schedule and will print results of given IPs. I think it is possible. just stuck on multiple IPs.

Comment: @MohiyoDeen I'd run the exec twice, since it's hard to differentiate between the two outputs. Do make sure your maximum execution time is sufficient.

Comment: I don't believe pinging multiple hosts in one go is even possible.

Comment: Then what should i do? is there any solution for that?

Comment: Maybe `foreach($_REQUEST['ips'] as $ips) {` and escape the `$ips`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: Local or not, if you're handling user inputs & doing this, you ARE in for a very bad time. Security and prevention before anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Create function to Ping Single IP Address

```
function pingIp($ip) {
    exec ("ping -n 2 ".$ip, $ping_output, $value);
    return $ping_output;
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['go'])){
//$arr = array('127.0.0.1','127.0.0.9','46.101.113.87','159.203.96.186');
  $arr =$_REQUEST['ip'];
for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++){
    ?>
    <pre>
    <?php
    print_r(pingIp($arr[$i]));
    echo('<br/><br/>');
}
}
```

Then get IPs from Form and Call that function as in given example.